# trigger an button click event on a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

a simple question but i cant find the answer, i have a jquery dialog:

```
$(function () {
    $('#my-dialog').dialog({
        modal: true, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', resizable: false, autoOpen: false,
        title: "@HMSW.Resources.Persona.Res_Strings.BuscaPersona",
        buttons: {
            "Accept": function () {
                $($(this).find('#target').val()).val($(this).find('#idPersonaSeleccionada').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    });
```

but my question is: how can i trigger the button ok (or any) from the dialog? the dialog contains a jqgrid, so in the ondoubleclickrow event of the jqgrid i need to trigger the `Accept` button

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: `ondblClickRow: function() { $('#my-dialog').find('button').eq(0).trigger('click'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("button span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Accept";
}).click();
```

js.fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/e4XBK/)

Comment: that works but if i have any other "accept" button on my dom?

Comment: You can narrow selector to ".ui-dialog button span" so you will be sure that you select button that was generated by $.dialog(). I suppose there will be no more than one dialog opened at one time.

Comment: dont know yet, this will be a dialog reused many times, an it may be open from another dialog, i wast tinking in somthing like:                 $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-button:contains("@Res_Button.Accept")').click(); but im not sure if this will work

Comment: i mean it work but not shure how this will work on a multiple dialog scenario